# Object Initializer for object collections

Tags: c#

I am wanting to find out if there is a way to initialize a `List<T>` where `T` is an `object` much like a simple collection gets initialized?

**[Simple Collection Initializer:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)**

```
List<int> digits = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

**[Object Collection Initilizer:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)**

```
 List<ChildObject> childObjects = new List<ChildObject>
 {       
        new ChildObject(){ Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 },
        new ChildObject(){ Name = "Whiskers", Age=2 },
        new ChildObject(){ Name = "Sasha", Age=14 }
 };
```

The question is, how and if you can do something like this?

```
 List<ChildObject> childObjects = new List<ChildObject>
 {       
       { "Sylvester", 8} , {"Whiskers", 2}, {"Sasha", 14}
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without creating your own class derived from `List<ChildObject>` as per Lee's answer. It's unfortunate that extension methods aren't considered for collection initalizers, otherwise this would work:

```
// This doesn't work, but it would if collection initializers checked
// extension methods.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ChildObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Add(this List<ChildObject> children, 
                           string name, int age)
    {
        children.Add(new ChildObject { Name = name, Age = age });
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ChildObject> children = new List<ChildObject>
        {
            { "Sylvester", 8 },
            { "Whiskers", 2 },
            { "Sasha", 14 }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for collection initializers, it's all about the collection's Add method. Just subclass the closed generic List over your type and make an Add method with the naked parameters. Like

```
public class MyColl : List<ChildObject>
{
    public void Add(string s1, int a1, int a2)
    {
        base.Add(new ChildObject(s1, a1, a2));
    }
}

public class ChildObject
{
    public ChildObject(string s1, int a1, int a2)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then calling it looks like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyColl x = new MyColl
        {
            {"boo", 2, 4},
            {"mang", 3, 5},
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The best you can probably do is something like this:

```
public class MyListOfChildObjects : List<ChildObject>
{
    public void Add( string name, int age )
    {
        Add ( new ChildObject { Name = name, Age = age } );
    }
}

var childObjects = new MyListOfChildObjects 
{
    { "Sylvester", 8 } , { "Whiskers", 2 }, { "Sasha", 14 }
};
```

You could make it more generic, but how would you know which arguments should be bound to each property?

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public void Add( params object[] arguments )
    {
        // what order should I bind the values to?
    }
}

var childObjects = new MyList<ChildObject>
{
    { "Sylvester", 8 } , { "Whiskers", 2 }, { "Sasha", 14 }
};
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness of the answer: having Add as extension method for List<ChildObject> still won't let to use collection initializer syntax as it doesn't compile (Error: "No overload for method 'Add' takes '2' arguments").

Answer (score 3):

You can get close by creating your own collection which extends `List<ChildObject>` and provide your own add method:

```
public class ChildObjectCollection : List<ChildObject>
{
    public void Add(string name, int age)
    {
        this.Add(new ChildObject(name, age));
    }
}
```

You can then initialise it like this:

```
var childObjects = new ChildObjectCollection
{
    { "Sylvester", 8} , {"Whiskers", 2}, {"Sasha", 1 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to that is to create a parameterized constructor on your class that accepts those arguments. That won't get you all the way, but you can at least do this:

```
List<ChildObject> childObjects = new List<ChildObject>
{       
      new ChildObject("Sylvester", 8) , 
      new ChildObject("Whiskers", 2), 
      new ChildObject("Sasha", 14)
};
```